# mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in

Tags: php, mysql

El problema que me informa es:

> Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in:
>   /home/miweb/public_html/depo2019/registro.php on line 61

Al revisar las lineas de comando funcionan en el servidor local pero al subirlos al hosting me da error, lo subo a un hosting gratuito y funciona bien. En mi hosting me dicen que no me pueden dar soporte.
Las líneas son las siguientes.

```
$insert = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO clientes(id, dni, apellido_nombre, 
direccion, barrio, orden,fecha_orden, abrigo, agua, arroz, azucar, cacao, 
calzado, chapas, choclo, colchones, durazno, fideos, galletas, harina, leche, 
mod_alim, panales, picadillo, membrana, tomate,  registrado)

VALUES(NULL,'$dni', '$apellido_nombre',  '$direccion', '$barrio',  
'$orden','$fecha_orden','$abrigo' '$agua', '$arroz','$arvejas', 
'$azucar','$cacao','$calzado', '$chapas', '$choclo', '$colchones', '$durazno', 
'$fideos', '$galletas', '$harina', '$leche', '$mod_alim', '$panales', 
'$picadillo', '$membrana', '$tomate', '$registrado')") or die(mysqli_error());
```

No veo la falla si alguien me puede ayudar. Desde ya, gracias.

Comment: Pásale la conexión a `mysqli_error()` de esta manera: `mysqli_error($conn)`, así te dirá cuál es el error que está ocurriendo.

Comment: Alejandro creo q t falta una coma (,) despues del campo .... '$abrigo' en el values ok agregasela y avisa saludos

Comment: Corregi la coma que falta y lo que hice fue agregar el mysqli_error($conn) y me da ahora.
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: Alejandro lo q el amigo Edgar t comento es totalmente correcto lo q puedes hacer tambien es declarar tu variable $dni = ""; con esto no deberias tener problema siempre q sea clave primaria y única tal cual como lo menciono Edgar.

Comment: el id es auto incrementado? porque si es auto comentado debe dejarlo en vacío

Answer (score 0):

El problema que sucede es que estás intentado insertar un NULL en el id de la tabla clientes; cosa que no se puede hacer porque el id debe ser una llave primaria y única. Te recomiendo que el id de la tabla lo hagas del tipo entero, único auto incremental.
De esta manera insertarías los registros correctamente y no lidiarías con los id's.

```
$insert = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO clientes(dni, apellido_nombre, 
direccion, barrio, orden,fecha_orden, abrigo, agua, arroz, azucar, arvejas, 
cacao, calzado, chapas, choclo, colchones, durazno, fideos, galletas, 
harina, leche, mod_alim, panales, picadillo, membrana, tomate,  registrado)

VALUES('$dni', '$apellido_nombre',  '$direccion', '$barrio',  
'$orden','$fecha_orden','$abrigo', '$agua', '$arroz','$azucar','$arvejas', 
'$cacao','$calzado', '$chapas', '$choclo', '$colchones', '$durazno', 
'$fideos', '$galletas', '$harina', '$leche', '$mod_alim', '$panales', 
'$picadillo', '$membrana', '$tomate', '$registrado')") or 
 die(mysqli_error());
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Yo lo solucione